# What does "Facebook gives me the willies" mean?

Tags: meaning

I saw a [Tweet](https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/1511206240667455489) by Elon Musk:

> Facebook gives me the willies

What does this mean? I tried to search but can't find any reasonable explanation for this.

Context:

[image]

Comment: [the willies](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/the%20willies): a nervous feeling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"The willies" means feelings of fear or nervousness. To say, "It gives me the willies" means it scares or upsets me.

Paradoxically, we also say, "It scares the willies out of me" to mean it makes me very afraid. One might think that having willies and having willies driven out of you would be opposites, but no, they're the same.

It's a very informal word. I wouldn't expect to find it in a scholarly paper or even a news report.